# Why reCAPTCHA v3 does not submit my form?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, captcha

I'm using reCaptcha v3 for a feedback form protection. It was working fine until a few days ago: I'm filling out the form, clicking the submit button and there is no any reaction.

I'd connected reCaptcha by the following steps:

1. Added script into `<head>...</head>`:

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
</head>
```

2. Designed a form:

```
<form id="contact-form" 
        action="/" 
        method="post" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data" 
        onsubmit="submitContactForm(token)"
    >
    <div class="contact-form-input">
        <label for="contact-form-name">
            Your name:
        </label>
        <input class="contact-form-required" 
            type="text" 
            name="contact-form-name" 
            placeholder="Name"
        />
    </div>
...
    <div class="contact-form-input">
        <div class="contact-form-btn-outline contact-form-btn-left contact-form-btn-narrow">
            <button 
                class="contact-form-btn g-recaptcha" 
                data-callback="submitContactForm" 
                data-sitekey="my_site_key"
            >
                Send message
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="contact-form-alert"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

3. Added following JS code:

```
function submitContactForm(e) {
    document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();
}
```

It all worked fine until few days ago: now `submitContactForm` function is not called by reCaptcha code. No any reactions in DOM, only "Send message" button being disabled while captcha is sending POST request to Google servers.

Surely, the backend side does not receive any POST requests.

Comment: Have you checked whether the browser console has anything to say?

Comment: Yes, there is no any errors or info.